# Publish Web Site Dialog is not opening in Visual studio Professional edition 2012

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012

When i try to open the Publish **Web Site Dialog** in VS 2012, **Publish Web Dialog** is opening.
Me and my friend using VS 2012, When i try to open the same project in my friend pc(File->Open Website) and click build->Publish Web Site, Publish Web Site Dialog is opening,but when i tried the same  procedure in my pc, to open the same project in my pc, **Publish Web Dialog is opening** instead of **Publish Web Site Dialog**
What will be the issues? I need to open **Publish Web Site dialog instead of Publish Web Dialog**
What i need to change?
Any ideas??
Here i attached the screenshots of Publish web and Publish Web Site[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Publish Web Dialog like the Publish Web Site Dialog. 
First of all you need to cretate a new profile from the main window. 
Step 1:Just click on the select box than on "create new profile". Give a name to your profile.
Step 2:Click on "Connection" menù on the left. In the window on the left choose the publish method which you need (ftp , filesystem etc.).
Step 3: Click on publish button (it is on the bottom)

Comment: Hi Darkito, i followed your step,In "connection" option i chosen Published method as File System and provided the target location, after clicking publish, published happen succesfully,but when i view the target location class files i.e(.cs) files still remains, if .cs files remains then published is not happened correct i think so. but when i use Publish Web Site Method in my friend PC, after publishing, .cs files doesn't available. What i need to proceed further to achieve this

Comment: It depends on what kind of web site you are going to publish. If it's a web form not compiled it's normal to have cs files. Otherwise if you are publishing an mvc application than you should not see cs files in the target location. You can compile your web site by selecting "precompile during publication" from the Settings menù (it is under connection menù item)

Comment: I am trying to publish the WCF Service application,during publishing i selected the "precompile during publication" option,then i am getting the following error Error "It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS."

Comment: Try to clean your solution: right click on project root and select "clean".

Comment: Sorry no clean option is available here, so i just rebuild the solution, still facing the same error.I opened my project as File->Open WebSite. I am using VS2012 Professional, how can i overcome from this error?

Comment: Thanks Darkito ,there is some problem in my web config file, i rectified it, its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Please select the settings check the precompile during publishing.

Then the publishing, .cs files doesn't available